# get date from jQuery UI date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I want to get date from my jQuery UI date picker.
In my input, I need to show date in "d MM yy" format as it is more readable for users. eg. "5 June 2015"

```
$("#from").datepicker({
       dayNamesMin: [ "S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S" ], 
       firstDay: 1,  
       dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
       onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
       $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
       }
   });
```

But when I need to use the input date value, I need it in "yyyy-mm-dd" format eg. 2015-04-30

The default getdate method gives me the medium date string.

```
var start = $("#from").datepicker( 'getDate' );
```

Is there any fast way to get "yyyy-mm-dd" format  instead of doing string manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formatDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

```
var dt = $("#from").datepicker( 'getDate' );
var start= $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  //storing parent element
  var parentElement = $('div.date');
  
  //bind the date picker to the parent
  parentElement.datepicker(
  {
                firstDay: 1,
                inline:true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                daysNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    });
   
   //when the parent is changed(clicked or submit) grab the value
   parentElement.on('change', function()
   {
      var selectedDate = $(this).val();//the selected date value
      console.warn(selectedDate);//logging the selected date
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="date"></div>
```